# Given 4 arrays, unsorted, find all possible quadruples with sum <m

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

Given four arrays of equal length which are not sorted and they have unique elements in them but across the arrays elements can clash so we were asked to pick one element from each array and satisfy this condition "x1+x2+x3+x4 < m" and count all possible solutions.

Can we do something better than sorting all arrays and doing it in O(n^3*logn)?

Comment: Can be done in O(n^2), what is the complexity you need?

Comment: @juvian I guess the naive solution is to iterate over every value of three arrays, and find a matching element in the fourth array using binary search; that would be N^3.logN.

Comment: @m69 naive is O(n^4)

Comment: @juvian can you elaborate on your O(n^2) approach?

Comment: @HimaniVirmani What's the issue with sorting all arrays anyway?

Comment: @vivek_23 no issues. with sorting arrays. just asking if better solution than O(n^3.logn) exists.

Comment: @HimaniVirmani ok, fair enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Generate an array with all the sums between elements from x1 and x2. This will have O(n^2) elements. Lets call it arr0
2. Do the same for x3 and x4. Lets call it arr1
3. Sort both
4. Now we have reduced the problem to finding the amount of sums < m between elements from 2 sorted arrays.

   ```
   p0 = 0
   p1 = arr1.length - 1
   qty = 0
   while(p0 != p1)
       while(p1 >= 0 and arr0[p0] + arr1[p1] >= m) p1--;
       if (p1 <= p0) break;
       qty += p1
       po++
   ```

This small algorithm will solve that in O(length(arr0) + length(arr1)), as p1 pointer always decreases and p0 always increases and for each loop we always increase or decrease one of them

Overall this gives us a O(n^2) to generate pairs, O(n^2 * log n^2) to sort them and O(n^2) to count the quadruples.

Comment: I thought so but it needs O(n^2) space.  It will work but `n` needs to be small. Of course, if OP clears that `n` is small, then this is the solution.

Comment: Sorry, the title says "find quadruples" but the question says "count solutions"... my mistake.

Comment: @m69 OP has stated that he just wants to count all possible solutions. Finding all would be O(n^4) as all possibilities could sum less than m